Is the red light hypnosis device in The Penguin based on real technology?
In episode 7 of The Penguin "Top Hat," Sofia Falcone captures Francis Cobb (played by Deirdre O'Connell), who is Oz's mother. Sofia has the psychiatrist, Dr. Julian Rush, use a device on Cobb that appears capable of hypnosis. The apparatus appears to be a rectangular LED panel. It emits red light moving back and forth. Using this device, Sofia and Rush manipulate Francis to reveal her life story with Oz, apparently to "break" her before their confrontation with him.

Given that both The Batman and its spin-off The Penguin take a more grounded approach compared to other Batman adaptations, I'm curious whether this device might be based on real technology. However, since it's still derived from comic books, it could simply be a fictional sci-fi element. Is there any real-world basis for this type of device?

Partial as the device portrayed itself might be a movie device prop.
Seems loosely based on real life research:
Red light therapy seems new and only a few tests were done on rats.
Light therapy itself has been used on those with PTSD:

Red Light Therapy For PTSD: A Promising Method?
Red light therapy has shown promise in helping individuals with PTSD. Learn about science, potential benefits, and applications.

https://www.lighttherapyinsiders.com/red-light-therapy-for-ptsd/
In The Penguin, the therapy used was recognised as a form of EDMR used to calm the patient.

Eye Movement Desensitization And Reprocessing (EMDR) can give the thoughts and feelings a different meaning .


Red And Near Infrared Light Effects On PTSD
The biggest concern right now is that there are only four studies on red light therapy for PTSD

Also seems red light therapy is used for depression, anxiety, and some brain conditions.
And:

But EMDR treatment works best when complemented with red light therapy. Why? Because red light therapy can help reduce the symptoms of PTSD, including insomnia.  Light plays a crucial role in the human body. Red light therapy is a non-invasive and non-pharmacological treatment option for those with PTSD. But how does it work?
Red light therapy boosts the cells' energy via natural light, increasing ATP (adenosine triphosphate) production. Thus damaged cells can heal, and new cells are produced quickly, creating a high functioning and optimal system. However, that's not the only thing red light therapy can do. Red light therapy improves an individual's sleep quality, which balances melatonin production and syncs the sleep-wake cycle.

https://www.kaiyanmedical.com/post/emdr-and-ptsd-on-veterans-can-light-therapy-help
But the device itself i have not researched
